# Plots with inverted secondary axis in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have combo chart plotted in Excel. However, I am having a difficulty trying to configure it to my desired presentation

This is how my chart output at the moment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn033.jpg

And I require it to look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlC75.jpg
where the secondary axis is below the primary axis on the same side.

Edit: I have managed to get here [image: here]

however, I require the blue chart to sit directly below the green chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your desired outcome, there's no need for two separate charts.  A single area chart with two series, one positive and the other negative, will accomplish the same thing.  A pseudo-panel/lattice chart effect can also be created by using gaps in the data series.  Or multiple-aligned charts can be used horizontally to create the panels.

[image: mirror area chart]

**EDIT**
To create the above image, using data from a table like this:
[image: data table]

**USING NEGATIVE VALUES**

1. Create an empty Area Chart (`Insert>Charts>2-D Area`).  It's best to do this on an empty cell, at least one row and column away from your data to prevent Excel from making (bad) decisions on it's own.
2. Add your data series.  In this case (based on your example) there are two series, A & B.  A is the positive series and B is the negative series.
   *The two blank cells in the column become the separation between the groups.  This is a shortcut-they are not necessary if you don't want gaps along the horizontal axis (like your example).  And, even if you do want gaps, there are better ways to do that-but that should probably be a separate question.*
   [image: unformatted version]

**OR, USING SECONDARY AXIS**

1. If your values are all positive (pointing up), but you want to display them negative (pointing down), you can use a secondary axis.  In this case you'll need to convert your B-Series values to positive.
2. Create a blank 2-D Area Chart (as above).
3. Add your data series (as above).
   [image: step_3]
4. Format your B-Series to plot on the secondary axis.
   [image: step_4]
5. Format your Secondary Axis to plot Values in Reverse Order.
   [image: step_5]
   *As you've discovered, the problem is the scales overlap and consequently they're "facing" one another, instead of having their "backs" together.  This is because they're essentially the same "size" (0-1) and they're occupying the same space relative to the horizontal axis.  So, we need to create enough "room" for them to both fit. So, we need to create a vertical axis that's roughly twice as tall and then move the two series to opposite sides of the horizontal axis. So...*
6. Format both the Primary and Secondary Axis with:

- Minimum Value = -1
- Maximum Value = 1
  [image: step_6]

And all those steps together:

[image]

7. Format the rest to taste.  For the original above, I removed all the axis, adjusted color and transparency, and grid lines to more closely resemble your example.

Note that both processes result in the same visual product, but they differ considerably in complexity.  Use the simplest that results in the product that best meets your needs.

Comment: Creating the chart such as the output you have for Namibia is the problem I am having. I want the secondary axis to be below the primary axis to get the blue and red portions as shown

Comment: I have added an edit to the question to show my progress, and precisely what I need to to do next

Comment: Why are you using a secondary axis, rather than negative values?  You can accomplish the same thing either way-but the secondary axis is more complicated (as you've found).  I'll put a bit more detail in my answer to see if it clarifies what's happening.

Comment: To your second comment, I think you're at my second option, Step 5.  You can probably solve your problem by jumping in at Step 6.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please explian the percentage on the image you required?

1. If you do not need the Y-axis, I suggest you create an auxiliary column, enter the formula `= -1 * cell of Series 6`.

Then select the Date, Series 5 and the auxiliary column to create a chart with one Y aixis, like the following image.

[image]

Then you could delete the Y-axis to avoid showing negative numbers.

2. If you need the Y-axis, it's better to create 2 charts, and then spliced together.

You may select area, set No fill for Chart Area for 2 charts.

Choose one series, set the the values of Y-axis in reverse order, besides, remove X-axis.

[image]

At last, set No line for Border for both 2 charts.
[image]

Comment: I've done all the required steps of method 2. How did you get them to be spliced together?